# Big Pipe is breaking ARIA accordion javascript functionality

Tags: 8

I'm trying to use this library for accordions on a Drupal 8 site:
https://scottaohara.github.io/a11y_accordions/

It works fine when not logged in, but if the user is logged in it doesn't work. Doesn't throw an error either.

I found that if I copy and paste the full script into the browser console it works so I started looking into loading order. I discovered that the issue was Big Pipe. If I turn off the module I don't have this issue.

I'm currently loading the script via my theme's libraries file.

Is there a way to make this script work with Big Pipe or do I have to find a different one?

EDIT:
This is how I'm doing it right now... its in a js file that's added to my site via my theme's libraries file:

```
(function (Drupal, $, window) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MY_THEME = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(window).on('load', function () {
        !function(t,e,a){"use strict";var r={};t.ARIAaccordion=r,r.NS="ARIAaccordion",r.AUTHOR="Scott O'Hara",r.VERSION="3.2.1",r.LICENSE="https://github.com/scottaohara/accessible_accordions/blob/master/LICENSE";var i="accordion",l=i+"__trigger",n=i+"__panel",o="[data-aria-accordion-heading]",d="[data-aria-accordion-panel]",c=0;r.create=function(){var t,a,s,u,A,g,h="none",b=e.querySelectorAll("[data-aria-accordion]");for(c+=1,g=0;g<b.length;g++){var f;if((t=b[g]).hasAttribute("id")||(t.id="acc_"+c+"-"+g),t.classList.add(i),e.querySelectorAll("#"+t.id+"> li").length?(a=e.querySelectorAll("#"+t.id+" li > "+d),s=e.querySelectorAll("#"+t.id+" li > "+o)):(a=e.querySelectorAll("#"+t.id+" > "+d),s=e.querySelectorAll("#"+t.id+" > "+o)),t.hasAttribute("data-default")&&(h=t.getAttribute("data-default")),A=t.hasAttribute("data-constant"),t.hasAttribute("data-multi"),t.hasAttribute("data-transition")){var y=t.querySelectorAll(d);for(f=0;f<y.length;f++)y[f].classList.add(n+"--transition")}for(r.setupPanels(t.id,a,h,A),r.setupHeadingButton(s,A),u=e.querySelectorAll("#"+t.id+"> li").length?e.querySelectorAll("#"+t.id+" li > "+o+" ."+l):e.querySelectorAll("#"+t.id+" > "+o+" ."+l),f=0;f<u.length;f++)u[f].addEventListener("click",r.actions),u[f].addEventListener("keydown",r.keytrolls)}},r.setupPanels=function(t,e,a,r){var i,l,o,d,c;for(i=0;i<e.length;i++)o=t+"_panel_"+(i+1),d=a,c=r,(l=e[i]).setAttribute("id",o),s(e[0],!0),l.classList.add(n),"none"!==d&&NaN!==parseInt(d)&&(d<=1?s(e[0],!1):d-1>=e.length?s(e[e.length-1],!1):s(e[d-1],!1)),(c&&"none"===d||NaN===parseInt(d))&&s(e[0],!1)},r.setupHeadingButton=function(t,a){var r,i,n,o,d,c;for(c=0;c<t.length;c++)i=(r=t[c]).nextElementSibling.id,n=e.getElementById(i).getAttribute("aria-hidden"),o=e.createElement("button"),d=r.textContent,r.innerHTML="",r.classList.add("accordion__heading"),o.setAttribute("type","button"),o.setAttribute("aria-controls",i),o.setAttribute("id",i+"_trigger"),o.classList.add(l),"false"===n?(u(o,!0),g(o,!0),a&&o.setAttribute("aria-disabled","true")):(u(o,!1),g(o,!1)),r.appendChild(o),o.appendChild(e.createTextNode(d))},r.actions=function(t){var a,i=this.id.replace(/_panel.*$/g,""),n=e.getElementById(this.getAttribute("aria-controls"));a=e.querySelectorAll("#"+i+"> li").length?e.querySelectorAll("#"+i+" li > "+o+" ."+l):e.querySelectorAll("#"+i+" > "+o+" ."+l),t.preventDefault(),r.togglePanel(t,i,n,a)},r.togglePanel=function(t,a,r,i){var l,n,o=t.target;if("true"!==o.getAttribute("aria-disabled")&&(l=o.getAttribute("aria-controls"),g(o,"true"),"true"===o.getAttribute("aria-expanded")?(u(o,"false"),s(r,"true")):(u(o,"true"),s(r,"false"),e.getElementById(a).hasAttribute("data-constant")&&A(o,"true")),e.getElementById(a).hasAttribute("data-constant")||!e.getElementById(a).hasAttribute("data-multi")))for(n=0;n<i.length;n++)o!==i[n]&&(g(i[n],"false"),l=i[n].getAttribute("aria-controls"),A(i[n],"false"),u(i[n],"false"),s(e.getElementById(l),"true"))},r.keytrolls=function(t){if(t.target.classList.contains(l)){var a,r=t.keyCode||t.which,i=this.id.replace(/_panel.*$/g,"");switch(a=e.querySelectorAll("#"+i+"> li").length?e.querySelectorAll("#"+i+" li > "+o+" ."+l):e.querySelectorAll("#"+i+" > "+o+" ."+l),r){case 35:t.preventDefault(),a[a.length-1].focus();break;case 36:t.preventDefault(),a[0].focus()}}},r.init=function(){r.create()};var s=function(t,e){t.setAttribute("aria-hidden",e)},u=function(t,e){t.setAttribute("aria-expanded",e)},A=function(t,e){t.setAttribute("aria-disabled",e)},g=function(t,e){t.setAttribute("data-current",e)};r.init()}(window,document);

      });
    }
  };

} (Drupal, jQuery, this));
```

Comment: Are you doing any other initialization, or just adding the script?  BigPipe requires the JSAPI (eg, attach behaviors) to be used properly for things to work.

Comment: How are you adding the script exactly? And in what context are you using it? Views? How exactly did you adjust the markup? How is the markup looking now? Please edit your question for clarification. Many thanks

Comment: My own mistake #1 when using BigPipe: Do not use something like `$(document).ready(...)`, you must use [Drupal.behaviors](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview)